# JDBC is refusing to use a specified password

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm getting an SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException with "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (**using password: NO**)"

```
mysql = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb/",
    "someuser",
    "somepassword"
);
```

As you can see, the password is indeed specified and yet the driver thinks it shouldn't use it. What am I doing wrong? I'm 100% sure the credentials are correct.

I've also tried specifying everything in the connection string like so:

```
mysql = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb?user=someuser&password=somepassword");
```

to no avail.

MySQL Community version 8.0.17

mysql-connector-java version 8.0.19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this in your MySQL workbench (or command line) : `ALTER USER 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'somepassword'`

Comment: That helped, thank you. Would you mind elaborating a little bit on why this helped?

Comment: Maybe the connector version use some different configurations than MySQL version. So what you need to do is to set the user authentication plugin to a basic `mysql_native_password`. More about auth plugin can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html) at the "ALTER USER Authentication Options" chapter. (MySQL 8.0 Reference manual)

Answer (score 0):

Use this connection string

```
mysql = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb","someuser","somepassword");
```